# When does the tangent microbundle of a closed orientable topological $4k$-manifold have a trivial rank 2 subbundle?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, manifolds, topological-manifolds

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Top}{Top}
\DeclareMathOperator{\co}{H}$Let $M$ be a closed orientable connected topological manifold of dimension $4k$ with $k > 1$. It is known ([David Frank, On the index of a tangent 2-field](https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(72)90011-0)) that if $M$ has a smooth structure, the necessary and sufficient condition for it to admit two linearly independent vector fields is the following:

> The Euler characteristic $\chi(M) = 0$ and the signature $\sigma(M)
>  \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$.

Do the same two conditions characterize whether the tangent microbundle $\tau M$ of $M$ has a rank 2 trivial subbundle?

The vanishing $\chi(M) = 0$ is evidently necessary, for instance by the Lefschetz fixed point theorem; it is also sufficient for $\tau M$ to have a rank **one** trivial subbundle by Corollary 1.5 in [Ronald J. Stern, On topological and piecewise linear vector fields](https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(75)90007-5).

Duane Randall has papers that work out the analogous characterization with non-orientable manifolds and manifolds of dimension $4k+1$, $4k+2$, $4k+3$, but they seem to leave the orientable 4k case unsettled in general.

[Duane Randall, CAT 2-fields on nonorientable CAT manifolds](https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/38.3.355)

[Duane Randall, On indices of tangent fields with finite singularities](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0081477)

[Duane Randall, On 4-manifolds and span-related numbers for CAT manifolds](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02567932)

Let me outline the formal part of (what seems to be) the right setup. By microbundle representation theorems we can write $\tau \colon M \rightarrow B\Top(4k)$ which we want to lift along a fibration
$$V_{4k,2}^{\Top} := \Top(4k) \,/\, \Top(4k,2) \rightarrow B\Top(4k,2) \rightarrow B\Top(4k) \, .$$
The primary obstruction should be the Bockstein of the $(4k-2)$nd Stiefel-Whitney class and vanish, similar to the smooth case. The next and final obstruction class will lie inside
$$\co^{4k}\left(M;\pi_{4k-1}(V_{4k,2}^{\Top})\right) \cong \pi_{4k-1}(V_{4k,2}^{\Top}) \cong \pi_{4k-1}(V_{4k,2}) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$$
where the second isomorphism is by Theorem 2.5 of Stern's paper. The problem then becomes showing that this class always corresponds to a pair of the form
$$\left(\chi(M), \,\frac{\sigma(M) \pm \chi(M)}{2} \!\!\!\mod{\!2}\right) \in \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \, .$$

Comment: Could you edit the question to include references for the claims you make? I hope it is not too much trouble.

Comment: MathJax note: preamble commands like `\DeclareMathOperator` should go in a single-dollar-sign math environment `$…$`, not a double-dollar-sign one `$$…$$`, or they will create an empty display environment.  Also, the closing dollar sign must not be followed by a newline, or else it will create a spurious blank line in the rendered post.  I have edited accordingly.